# Using Angular11, how does my HomeComponent retrieve the data provided by the Subject in DataService?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, subject

In order to make the data accessible through out the app, I created a new service called the DataService where I want to store my data coming from the API in a Subject.
While I do get the data, I cen see the array of objects in a log from DataService, my array in HomeComponent that should get the data is undefined in the console:

[browser inspector console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nODO.png)

I imagine I have some stupid errors in my code, I am a beginer. Could you help me ?

HomeComponent:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from '../../shared/services/data.service';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import {Article} from '../../shared/models/article';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() articles?: Article[];
  articleSubscription?: Subscription;
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.emitArticlesSubject(this.dataService.loadArticles());
    this.articleSubscription =
      this.dataService.articlesSubject.subscribe(
        (articles) => {
          this.articles = articles;
        }
      );
    console.log('HOME COMPONENT: ngOnInit: this.articles : ' + JSON.stringify(this.articles));
  }

}
```

DataService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject, Subject} from 'rxjs';
import {ArticleService} from './article.service';
import {Article} from '../models/article';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  articles?: Article[];
  message = 'Aucun résultat ne correspond à votre recherche.';
  articlesSubject = new Subject<Article[]>();
  constructor(private articleService: ArticleService) { }

  emitArticlesSubject(action: any): void {
    this.articlesSubject.next(action);
  }

  /**
   * Method to be served as a parameter
   * to the 'emitArticlesSubject' method
   * to load articles sorted by date.
   */
  loadArticles(): any {
    this.articleService.getAll().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.articles = data._embedded.articles;
        console.log('DataService: loadArticles() : ' + JSON.stringify(this.articles));
      },
      error => {
        console.log('ERROR: DataService not able to loadArticles !' );
      }
    );
  }
  /**
   * Method to be served as a parameter
   * to the 'emitArticlesSubject' method
   * to load articles sorted by last activity.
   */
  loadArticlesByActivity(): any {
    this.articleService.getAllSortedByActivity().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.articles = data._embedded.articles;
      },
      error => {
        console.log('ERROR: DataService not able to loadArticlesByActivity');
      }
    );
  }
}
```

ArticleService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {Article} from '../models/article';
import {ResponseEntities} from '../../core/ResponseEntities';

const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/articles';
const queryUrl = '?search=';
const dateUrl = '?sort=date,desc';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ArticleService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAll(): Observable<ResponseEntities<Article[]>> {
    return this.http.get<ResponseEntities<Article[]>>(`${baseUrl}${dateUrl}`);
  }
  getAllSortedByActivity(): Observable<ResponseEntities<Article[]>> {
    return this.http.get<ResponseEntities<Article[]>>(`${baseUrl}/${dateUrl}`);
  }
  search(term: string): Observable<ResponseEntities<Article[]>> {
    return this.http.get<ResponseEntities<Article[]>>(`${baseUrl}/${queryUrl}${term}`);
  }
  get(id: any): Observable<Article> {
    return this.http.get<Article>(`${baseUrl}/${id}`);
  }
  create(data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(baseUrl, data);
  }

  update(id: any, data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(`${baseUrl}/${id}`, data);
  }

  delete(id: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(`${baseUrl}/${id}`);
  }

  deleteAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(baseUrl);
  }

  findByTag(tag: any): Observable<Article[]> {
    return this.http.get<Article[]>(`${baseUrl}?tag=${tag}`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be related to subscription in data service.

```
this.dataService.emitArticlesSubject(this.dataService.loadArticles());
```

in this line emitArticlesSubject() called. but loadArticles() subscribed to underlaying service. emitArticlesSubject() only call loadArticles() and does not wait for its subscription to get complete. that causes articlss to be undefined. you should use promise in loadArticles() or change your service structures and call ArticleService directly in your HomeComponent.

Comment: That must be it. Thank you, I will look up how to make a promise. I would like to keep DataService to keep my data in there.

Comment: this link https://codesource.io/using-promises-to-make-http-requests-in-angular/ could help

Answer (score 0):

In your HomeComponent you are console logging the contents of this.articles before the articles have actually been fetched. If you want to log the articles after they have been fetched, you can console log in the subscription instead:

```
this.articleSubscription =
  this.dataService.articlesSubject.subscribe(
  (articles) => {
    this.articles = articles;
    console.log('HOME COMPONENT: ngOnInit: this.articles : ' + JSON.stringify(this.articles));
  }
);
```

Comment: this way nothing shows in the console. It seems my .subscribe is not working.